# When should I redefining numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

In Python 2, I can redefine any number with the `ctypes` module, e.g. number `2` to `3`:

```
import ctypes

value = 2
ob_ival_offset = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_size_t) + ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)
ob_ival = ctypes.c_int.from_address(id(value)+ob_ival_offset)
ob_ival.value = 3

print 1+1
```

When should I ever need to do this?

Comment: Your question works as an answer if read in a sarcastic tone shouted from a disgruntled unemployed person from an indistinct crowd of mall people.

Answer (score 7):

Never.

Answer (score 1):

You have a chance on advent of code, look, this guy switched `+` and `*` operators to complete part 2 in one shot:

https://twitter.com/jhawthorn/status/1339804747394510850?s=19

[image]

Answer (score -3):

when you want to redefine number 2 in python)
and because everything is an object, but you probably shouldn't do that, and this is not a real question)